# HMAC SHA256 by using a static key + text as a key

Tags: hash, salt, sha, hmac

Maybe it's not a good idea, but I would like to check it with you.
When using HMAC SHA to hash a clear text value (string max 30 char) I need to use a key (256) but in my scenario this key is static and always the same each time I need to hash a value.
Also let's consider that this key is safely managed in my App.

It gives something like that :

```
var textToHash = "hellopassword"
var textHashed = HMACSHA256(Static256Key, textToHash)
// when compare hash
if (HMACSHA256(Static256Key, "hellopassword") == textHashed) return "OK";
```

I'm wondering if it's possible and more secure to make the Static256Key more dynamic by appending to the Static256Key the clear text value itself.
It will give something like that

```
var textToHash = "hellopassword"
var textHashed = HMACSHA256(Static256Key + textToHash, textToHash)
// when compare hash
if (HMACSHA256(Static256Key + "hellopassword", "hellopassword") == textHashed) return "OK";
```

Is it something that I can consider, or maybe I totally miss something here ?

Comment: You tell *what* you do, not *why*. It is impossible to say if it makes any sense until you tell what is goal, what problem are you trying to solve.

Comment: @mentallurg Ok, sorry, the goal is to hash short string (max 30 char) within a database. Then, for some functional reason, we need to make some checks and searchs across the hash for one specific string. In my example. We will hash a first time "hellopassword" string. Then, in another session, we should be able to check if we have a matching hash for "hellopassword". For the moment we are just hashing it with HMAC and a static key (assuming the key is well managed). I'm wondering if it makes sense to make the key more dynamic, to enforce the security (because the key will be more "unique" by h

Comment: The fixed key enables you to check the equality. Adding the message into key will increase the cost and [can be problematic](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/67341/18298). Stay with fixed key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> wondering if it's possible

Sure. Either input to the HMAC function can be arbitrary length, concatenation exists, no reason this wouldn't be possible.

> and more secure

Not at all. The security of HMAC depends on only two (EDIT: three) things:

- The quality of the hash function (not changed)
- The entropy (unguessability) of the key (not changed).
- [EDITED:] The key not being subject to certain collision-with-itself problems in the HMAC construction, which can be avoided by keeping it shorter than the hash function block length.

Since a plain text value has no entropy (1 possible value, log2(1) = 0 bits of entropy), all of the entropy of the key comes from the static secret as before.

As a side note, [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) already consists (in part) of a concatenation of (a modified version of) the key with the message. Doing that concatenation again gains you nothing.

---

EDIT: As [@kelalaka's comment](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/260325/hmac-sha256-by-using-a-static-key-text-as-a-key/260329#comment538009_260325) points out, there are actually dangers in making the key longer - it can result in the key adding *less* security than expected for its entropy - so don't do that.